# Scroll a UICollectionView when scrolling on a UIButton over it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview

I have a view with an horizontal UICollectionView and two UIButton over it (fixed on the right and left side with 25% screen width).

My need is to scroll the collectionView when I start to drag over a button without loosing the tap gesture of the button.

I tried to override the touchesMoved of my button and send the touches and event to my collectionView but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonDidTouchesMoved:withEvent:)]) {
        [self.delegate buttonDidTouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

How can I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

subclass collectionView and override

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
if ([view isKindOfClass:UIButton.class]) {
    return YES;
}
return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
```

}

this solved my problem without loosing button tap.